# Read standard library header file in terminal

Tags: c, man, documentation, header-file

is there any way to read a standard header file, say float.h , in terminal ?  Sometimes it would be nice to know what are the names of some values, say max value of float or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean "read"? If you mean you want to revise contents of a particular file you can go with a dozen of different options (i.e. `less float.h`, `vi float.h`, `vim float.h`, `nano float.h`). It mostly depends on your system and packages that are available.

Comment: Also, `grep MAXFLOAT float.h` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily "read" a header file by invoking the C preprocessor on a short program that just includes it:

```
echo '#include <float.h>' | cpp
```

But you'll find that there's not much useful output since all that header file does is define macros, which `cpp` happily memorizes then does not use.

If you want instead to know the max value of float or something like that, you could write a slightly longer program that actually asks for that:

```
(echo '#include <float.h>'; echo FLT_MAX) | cpp
```